# Which version of MySQL for Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have the 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 on my machine. I want to install the MySQL server from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). But I am confused which version to download.

My best guess is that, since Ubuntu is apparently a Debian distribution, I should go for the "Debian Linux 6.0 (x86, 64-bit), DEB" version of MySQL. Any pointers would really help.

Comment: Use MariaDB... lol. This question is not well suited for this site though. Try the superuser site.

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`?

Comment: You can use the DEB or generic 64-bit TAR archive. Why not just `apt-get install mysql-server`?

Comment: Stability is important. `apt-get` installs the most recent stable version of MySQL Server. So do not doubt and use it :)

Comment: I downloaded the Debian version mentioned in my question, but the software center gave me the warning when i tried to install "The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath."

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the "Linux - Generic (glibc 2.5) (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive" and installed it following the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html. Did not give me any problems as of yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Will give you the most recent MySQL server that works with your machine.

Comment: Does that download the community server, Enterprise edition, or cluster server?

Comment: I am not sure. I installed my server that way, and it seems to be working just like a MySQL server.

Comment: I tried apt-get but it looks like it is downloading the 5.5 version, while the MySQL site has a 5.6 version.

Comment: It may be due to outdated software on your system.

Comment: I have the latest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version and all system updates till date installed.

Comment: It is not correct to say that this will give you the most recent version that works with his machine. It will give the version officially supported by the Ubuntu package maintainers. This is not the same thing.